# Unix script command breaks terminal when unbuffering

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, pipe, tty

Sorry for the wonky title, maybe someone can improve it.

I'm using the [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)) command within a Python subprocess to unbuffer the output a command. I then read a single line from that process, and lastly I print some text. Here is my code (this file is named `script.py`):

```py
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(["script", "-q", "-c", "cat script.py", "/dev/null"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# proc = subprocess.Popen(["stdbuf", "-oL", "-eL", "cat", "script.py"],
#                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

proc.stdout.readline()

print("printing before...")
print("printing before...")
print("printing before...")

time.sleep(2)

print("printing after...")
print("printing after...")
print("printing after...")
```

I'm getting this absolutely bizarre behavior, such that when the subprocess writes to stdout, subsequent python print statements include several spaces after each line, until the process is terminated. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

As far as I can tell, it's printing the same number of spaces as there are columns in the terminal, after each line. I think this might have something to do with carriage returns, but I really have no idea. I can't understand why this would affect python's output at all, since I'm suppressing both `stdout` and `stderr` when doing a `Popen`.

I'm running this on arch linux, python version 3.8.6 and `uname -a` outputs:

```
Linux carbon 5.9.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun, 22 Nov 2020 14:16:59 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please let me know if there is any other information I can give.

Comment: Probably the output is a single byte which moves the cursor down one line; vertical tab?

Comment: Your program seems odd, I guess `cat` is just a placeholder here, but it's really unclear what your code is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: What the code is attempting to do isn't really important, I'm just trying to understand the behavior given the code, specifically why python's printing is affected by a subprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your subprocess `stdin` is still a TTY, `script` has reached around and changed its mode for handling CR and LF. Your first 3 prints are made while `script` is still running in the background. During the sleep, `script` fixes the terminal and exits. If you wait for your subprocess to complete, the problem goes away... usually. There is a chance that a signal will keep `script` from cleaning up after itself and ruin the rest of your session. Likely the better option is to redirect stdin.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["script", "-q", "-c", "cat script.py", "/dev/null"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This is all quite risky. If the executed program writes enough data to fill its stdout pipe, it will hang. If you just want the first line of a program that expects to run under at TTY, you could use `pty.spawn` to do the work. Interestingly, its documentation has an [EXAMPLE `script` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html#example).